# How can I reduce the file size of a Video&Image without losing quality?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Actually i tried this but it has more differ when compared to my original video..

**pickerController.videoQuality = UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeMedium**;

If I choose **UIImagePickerControllerQualityTypeHigh** the size remains same. Help me..

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if you want to resize or compress or both.

Below is the code for just compression :

Use [JPEG Compression](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) in two simple steps:

**1) Convert UIImage to NSData**

```
UIImage *rainyImage =[UImage imageNamed:@"rainy.jpg"];
NSData *imgData= UIImageJPEGRepresentation(rainyImage,0.1 /*compressionQuality*/);
```

this is lossy compression and image size is reduced.

**2) Convert back to UIImage**

```
UIImage *image=[UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
```

For scaling you can use answer provided by Matteo Gobbi. But scaling might not be a the best alternative. You would rather prefer to have a thumbnail of the actual image by compression because scaling might make look your image bad on a retina display device.